# How to set directory where Visual Studio compiles LESS files?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2012, less

I am using VS 2012 on Win 7. Currently (by default, I assume) it compiles LESS files to CSS on save to the same directory as the LESS file.

I would rather save all my CSS files to a "css" directory next to the "less" directory. I'm coming from the Mac using CodeKit to compile, and here you can choose an output path. I can't figure out how to set the output path in VS.

What I am looking for is:

```
-Projectroot
----less
----css
----js
etc.
```

Where my LESS files are all in "/less" and the compiled css goes to "/css"

Comment: you assume wrong... vs2012 does not compile less file. there are various plugin that do this. It depends on the one you are using and its configuration

Comment: yes, I am using MS's "web essentials" extension. Is there a better way?

Comment: with https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/ you can put them where you want. it creates css on the fly with less files

Answer (score 4):

If you're working in a team you'll probably want them to have the same CSS output folder as yours (and not telling each one of them to change their default Web Essentials settings) so the best way is to output your setting per Visual Studio Solution.

1. In Visual Studio menu go to ***WEB ESSENTIALS > Create solution settings***:

   [image]
2. A new folder and file will be created under your solution:

   [image]

   Open the generated file ***WebEssentials-Settings.json*** and change the
   property ***OutputDirectory*** under ***Less*** to your desired folder path:

   [image]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried going to TOOLS > OPTIONS > WEB ESSENTIALS > LESS and set a custom output directory?